# facing issue with loading ngResource in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am facing the below problem, while loading `ngResource` module into `loginService`.

```
Error message: Unknown provider: $ngResourceProvider <- $ngResource <- loginService
```

Below is my code. Please help. 
Thank you in advance.

```
App.js

var app=angular.module('exampleApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider
    .state('login',{
        url:'/login',
        templateUrl:'login.html',
        controller:'loginController'
    })
    .state('dashboard',{
        url:'/dashboard',
        templateUrl:'dashboard.html'
    });
});

app.controller('loginController',['$scope','loginService', function($scope,loginService){

    $scope.signin=function() {

         loginService.authenticate($.param({username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}),function(authenticationResult){

    var authToken = authenticationResult.token;
      $rootScope.authToken = authToken;
      console.log('token ::'+authToken);
    });

    }

}]);

app.service('loginService', ['$ngResource', function($scope,$resource){


return $resource('http://localhost:7001/springangulardemo:action', {},
            {
                authenticate: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {'action' : 'authenticate'},
                    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                },
            }
        );

}])
```

Comment: are you included angular-resource.js?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `$ngResource` in service just add `ngResource` in app module

```
angular.module('exampleApp', ['ui.router','ngResource']);
```